# How to fill an array , print it and sort it with bubble sort MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Im working on a homework which asks for the following.

1) create an array
2) save the ints the user gives (10)
3) print the number with comma between
4) sort them with buble sort and print them

here is my code whichdoes the first 3 steps , but at the 3rd steps something goes wrong with my code and it doesnt print all the numbers but only the last.

```
.data

array: .word 0:40
promtp: .asciiz "Give integer: \n"
promtp1: .asciiz "Unsorted Array: \n"


.text


 jal read

read:
    la $t0, 0   #count variable
    b readLoop


readLoop:
    beq $t0, 40, end   #branch if equal to 40, 10 items
    li $v0, 4       #Print string
    la $a0, promtp       #load prompt
    syscall
    li $v0, 5       #read int
    syscall 
    sw $v0, array       #store input in array ERROR HERE
    addi  $t0, $t0, 4   #add by 4 to counter
    b readLoop

end:

    li $v0, 4       #Print string
    la $a0, promtp1       #load prompt
    syscall

    la $t0, 0
while:

    beq $t0,40,end1
    lw $t6,array($t0)

    li $v0,1
    move $a0,$t6
    syscall

    li $a0, 44
        li $v0, 11
        syscall

    addi $t0, $t0 , 4
    b while

end1:


li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sw $v0, array       #store input in array ERROR HERE
```

This will store value in register `$v0` into memory at address `array`.

All of them.

At the same place in memory.

Judging by the printing of array code, I think you may wanted to do `sw $v0,array($t0)` in input loop, maybe?

Comment: you are correct bro , thanks lot that was the problem

Comment: any tips for buble sort?

Comment: @GioZio you can "accept" a correct answer. If you have another question, please ask a new question - this site is not a tutorial dialogue!